# SPARQL: select sparql query to get data from a file

Tags: sparql, rdf, rdfs, turtle-rdf

I need some help, I am new to SPARQL. I got stuck in this query I have to build, in which I have to get all musicians that have participed in a song with all 4 Beatles (excluding Uncredited as a possible answer).

What I have donw until now, but I am not really sure it is correct.

```
SELECT ?musicianName ?songTitle ?role
WHERE {
    ?song ?role ?musician .
    ?song rdfs:label ?songTitle .
    ?musician rdfs:label ?musicianName .
    FILTER (?musician NOT IN ("John Lennon", "Paul McCartney", "George Harrison", "Ringo Starr", "Uncredited"))
}
```

The data file is below:
Data File (Beatles.ttl)

```
 @prefix c:     <http://beatlesExample/ns/class/> .
    @prefix t:     <http://beatlesExample/ns/title/> .
    @prefix pi:     <http://beatlesExample/ns/playsInstrument/> .
    @prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
    @prefix m:     <http://beatlesExample/ns/musician/> .


t:MagicalMysteryTour  a         c:Song ;
        rdfs:label              "Magical Mystery Tour" ;
        pi:acousticrhythmguitar  m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:bass                  m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:drums                 m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:leadguitar            m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:percussion            m:RingoStarr , m:NeilAspinall , m:MalEvans , m:GeorgeHarrison , m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:piano                 m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:trumpet               m:ElgarHowarth , m:JohnWilbraham , m:DavidMason , m:RoyCopestake ;
        pi:vocals                m:JohnLennon , m:PaulMcCartney , m:GeorgeHarrison .

t:PennyLane  a                  c:Song ;
        rdfs:label              "Penny Lane" ;
        pi:acousticguitar        m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:backingvocals         m:JohnLennon , m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:bassguitar            m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:doublebass            m:FrankClarke ;
        pi:drums                 m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:electricguitar        m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:flutesorpiccolos      m:PGoody , m:RaySwinfield , m:MannyWinters , m:DennisWalton ;
        pi:guitar                m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:handclaps             m:GeorgeHarrison , m:JohnLennon , m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:harmonium             m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:oboesorcoranglais     m:DickMorgan , m:MikeWinfield ;
        pi:piano                 m:JohnLennon , m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:tambourine            m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:trumpetsorflugelhorn  m:FreddyClayton , m:LeonCalvert , m:BertCourtley , m:DuncanCampbell , m:DavidMason ;
        pi:tubularbells          m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:vocals                m:PaulMcCartney .

t:NotASecondTime  a             c:Song ;
        rdfs:label              "Not A Second Time" ;
        pi:acousticrhythmguitar  m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:bass                  m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:drums                 m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:piano                 m:GeorgeMartin ;
        pi:vocals                m:JohnLennon .

t:Yesterday  a      c:Song ;
        rdfs:label  "Yesterday" ;
        pi:cello     m:FranciscoGabarro ;
        pi:guitar    m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:viola     m:KennethEssex ;
        pi:violin    m:TonyGilbert , m:SidneySax ;
        pi:vocals    m:PaulMcCartney .

t:LosParanoias  a         c:Song ;
        rdfs:label        "Los Paranoias" ;
        pi:acousticguitar  m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:percussion      m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:shaker          m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:vocals          m:PaulMcCartney .


t:LikeDreamersDo  a     c:Song ;
        rdfs:label      "Like Dreamers Do" ;
        pi:bass          m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:drums         m:PeteBest ;
        pi:leadguitar    m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:rhythmguitar  m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:vocals        m:PaulMcCartney .

t:IGotToFindMyBaby  a   c:Song ;
        rdfs:label      "I Got To Find My Baby" ;
        pi:bass          m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:drums         m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:harmonica     m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:leadguitar    m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:rhythmguitar  m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:vocals        m:JohnLennon .

t:Revolution1  a          c:Song ;
        rdfs:label        "Revolution 1" ;
        pi:Hammondorgan    m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:acousticguitar  m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:backingvocals   m:FrancieSchwartz , m:GeorgeHarrison , m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:bass            m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:drums           m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:leadguitar      m:GeorgeHarrison , m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:piano           m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:trombone        m:JPower , m:DonLang , m:BillPovey , m:RexMorris ;
        pi:trumpet         m:FreddyClayton , m:DerekWatkins ;
        pi:vocals          m:JohnLennon .

t:DizzyMissLizzy  a                  c:Song ;
        rdfs:label                   "Dizzy Miss Lizzy" ;
        pi:Hammondorgan               m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:HohnerPianetelectricpiano  m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:bass                       m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:cowbell                    m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:double-trackedleadguitar   m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:drums                      m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:rhythmguitar               m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:vocals                     m:JohnLennon .

t:YesItIs  a                    c:Song ;
        rdfs:label              "Yes It Is" ;
        pi:acousticrhythmguitar  m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:bass                  m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:drums                 m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:harmonyvocals         m:GeorgeHarrison , m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:leadguitar            m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:tambourine            m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:vocals                m:JohnLennon .

t:IWannaBeYourMan  a     c:Song ;
        rdfs:label       "I Wanna Be Your Man" ;
        pi:Hammondorgan   m:GeorgeMartin ;
        pi:backingvocals  m:PaulMcCartney , m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:bass           m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:drums          m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:leadguitar     m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:maracas        m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:rhythmguitar   m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:vocals         m:RingoStarr .

t:ThingsWeSaidToday  a          c:Song ;
        rdfs:label              "Things We Said Today" ;
        pi:acousticrhythmguitar  m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:bass                  m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:drums                 m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:leadguitar            m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:piano                 m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:tambourine            m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:vocals                m:PaulMcCartney .

t:HallelujahILoveHerSo
        a           c:Song ;
        rdfs:label  "Hallelujah, I Love Her So" ;
        pi:bass      m:StuartSutcliffe ;
        pi:guitar    m:GeorgeHarrison , m:PaulMcCartney , m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:vocals    m:PaulMcCartney .

t:OldBrownShoe  a        c:Song ;
        rdfs:label       "Old Brown Shoe" ;
        pi:backingvocals  m:JohnLennon , m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:bass           m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:drums          m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:guitar         m:GeorgeHarrison , m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:organ          m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:piano          m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:vocals         m:GeorgeHarrison .

t:GoodNight  a           c:Song ;
        rdfs:label       "Good Night" ;
        pi:12violins      m:Uncredited ;
        pi:backingvocals  m:MikeRedway , m:PatWhitmore , m:FredLucas , m:ValStockwell , m:IreneKing , m:IngridThomas , m:KenBarrie , m:RossGilmour ;
        pi:celesta        m:GeorgeMartin ;
        pi:clarinet       m:Uncredited ;
        pi:doublebass     m:Uncredited ;
        pi:harp           m:Uncredited ;
        pi:horn           m:Uncredited ;
        pi:threecellos    m:Uncredited ;
        pi:threeflutes    m:Uncredited ;
        pi:threeviolas    m:Uncredited ;
        pi:vibraphone     m:Uncredited ;
        pi:vocals         m:RingoStarr .

t:MemphisTennessee  a   c:Song ;
        rdfs:label      "Memphis, Tennessee" ;
        pi:bass          m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:drums         m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:leadguitar    m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:rhythmguitar  m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:vocals        m:JohnLennon .

t:TicketToRide  a                   c:Song ;
        rdfs:label                  "Ticket To Ride" ;
        pi:bass                      m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:double-trackedleadvocals  m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:drums                     m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:handclaps                 m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:harmonyvocals             m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:leadguitar                m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:rhythmguitar              m:GeorgeHarrison , m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:tambourine                m:RingoStarr .

t:Ob-La-DiOb-La-Da  a      c:Song ;
        rdfs:label         "Ob-La-Di, Ob-La-Da" ;
        pi:acousticguitar   m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:backingvocals    m:JohnLennon , m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:bass             m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:bongo            m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:drums            m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:handclaps        m:JohnLennon , m:PaulMcCartney , m:GeorgeHarrison , m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:percussion       m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:piano            m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:threesaxophones  m:Uncredited ;
        pi:vocals           m:PaulMcCartney .

t:LetItBe  a              c:Song ;
        rdfs:label        "Let It Be" ;
        pi:backingvocals   m:JohnLennon , m:LindaMcCartney , m:PaulMcCartney , m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:bassguitar      m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:cello           m:Uncredited ;
        pi:drums           m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:electricpiano   m:BillyPreston ;
        pi:leadguitar      m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:maracas         m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:organ           m:BillyPreston ;
        pi:piano           m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:tenorsaxophone  m:Uncredited ;
        pi:twotrombones    m:Uncredited ;
        pi:twotrumpets     m:Uncredited ;
        pi:vocals          m:PaulMcCartney .


t:IGotAWoman  a         c:Song ;
        rdfs:label      "I Got A Woman" ;
        pi:bass          m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:drums         m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:leadguitar    m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:rhythmguitar  m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:vocals        m:JohnLennon .

t:TheSaints  a          c:Song ;
        rdfs:label      "The Saints" ;
        pi:bass          m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:drums         m:PeteBest ;
        pi:leadguitar    m:TonySheridan , m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:rhythmguitar  m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:vocals        m:TonySheridan .

t:LendMeYourComb  a     c:Song ;
        rdfs:label      "Lend Me Your Comb" ;
        pi:bass          m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:drums         m:RingoStarr ;
        pi:leadguitar    m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:rhythmguitar  m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:vocals        m:GeorgeHarrison , m:PaulMcCartney , m:JohnLennon .

t:BesameMucho  a        c:Song ;
        rdfs:label      "Besame Mucho" ;
        pi:bass          m:PaulMcCartney ;
        pi:drums         m:PeteBest ;
        pi:leadguitar    m:GeorgeHarrison ;
        pi:rhythmguitar  m:JohnLennon ;
        pi:vocals        m:PaulMcCartney .
```

Comment: that's for sure not correct. The first step for you is to find the query that returns are songs with all 4 Beatles. Then you can't simply use the name in your `FILTER NOT` clause but have to use their URIs. That said, you have n labels at all for all musicians in your dataset, so that's not gonna work.

Comment: `SELECT ?musician ?songTitle ?role
WHERE {?song ?role1 m:PaulMcCartney; ?role2 m:JohnLennon; ?role3 m:RingoStarr; ?role4 m:GeorgeHarrison .
    ?song ?role ?musician .
    ?song rdfs:label ?songTitle .
    
    FILTER (?musician NOT IN (m:PaulMcCartney, m:JohnLennon, m:RingoStarr, m:GeorgeHarrison, m:Uncredited))
}`

Comment: I'd also add `FILTER (?role NOT in (rdfs:label, rdf:type))` and probably `DISTINCT`.

Comment: True, I already did it in one of my comments in the previous question from the TO, forgot it this time ...